# Intellij / Java making file to write notes

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How can I make a file within my program so I can write note for myself? I am aware that I can comment within the code; however, I want to have a dedicated file so I can write plain text.

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from adding a text file to the project for this purpose?

Comment: More info on scratches here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/scratches.html#d753829e38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you update to intellij 14, you can use the scratches functionality: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/09/intellij-idea-14-eap-138-2210-brings-scratch-files-and-better-mercurial-integration/